# How do I write .next() when wrapped in an extra div?

Tags: jquery

I wrote a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjKr7/1/), I don't use `.next()` very often but when I do I make sure the button that calls the `.next()` is tucked in a nice div.

When naked ex. `<a href="#" class="add-sub">add</a>` it's fine.

When wrapped in a div`<div><a href="#" class="add-sub">add</a></div>`, my line `clone.appendTo(jQuery(el).next().find('.sub'));` doesn't work well.

I know this is an easy little change, but I've decided I should ask this question and get a little lesson in `.next`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tjKr7/1/)

Comment: You need to traverse up one node.

Comment: I see that for trans-versing `.parent()` is the trick.. thanks to Arun, I am off to study .parent and .next because they always get me they seem so simple but I never use them in the right context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you wrap it you need to find the `next()` of the wrapper element (you can use `.parent()` to get the wrapper)

```
clone.appendTo(jQuery(el).parent().next().find('.sub'));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PFPZk/)

Comment: You need to look more closely at the question and your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tjKr7/3/

Comment: You are using the wrong Fiddle. OP updated the Fiddle link after posting http://jsfiddle.net/tjKr7/1/

Comment: @doitlikejustin Again, you need to read the question more carefully. OP is asking what to do in the case that he wraps his toggle in a div. You need to remove his working link that doesn't require upward traversal, then it will work. He's not asking what to do when you stack two toggles next to each other.

Comment: @doitlikejustin it doesn't work because the OP has two add links which will not the correct case you need to remove the non-wrapped `a` link

Comment: Yeah just showing the different placements of the toggle... to Arun, or anyone else, I see `.parent()` is a good solution.. how do I write it when I keep nesting it with divs?

Comment: .parent, and .next always confuse me.. honestly I need to study the doc on them a little more.. most jQuery callbacks are easy to wrap your head around without the docs, but these two get me everytime lol

Comment: I would either bind the event to the most outer div, or I would attach a class to the most outer div and then use `.closest('.class').next()`

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry then you can add a class to the top wrapper element as then use `.closet()` ex `clone.appendTo(jQuery(el).closest('.my-wrapper').next().find('.sub'));` ex http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PFPZk/2/

Comment: ok thanks, this actually(thinking about it in layman's terms) makes sense. so if i nest the toggle in a series of divs ex <div class="my-wrapper"><div><div>toggle</div></div</div> it says the closest .my-wrapper to take it out of the nest and then says find the next .sub, which is the next block down. Does that sound about right, in my head I can picture it, IDK if I made sense of it, I see why there are specific programming terms, but I like to look at it in layman's terms.

Comment: Sorry if that sounded confusing, but yeah it makes sense to me now. Except, if we find our way out of the nested divs by using closest, how are we nesting into find `.sub`, saying that makes sense, it would be using the .find that nests into the table and finds the target? Yeah? I fiddled with it and this actually helped a ton in making sense, I am noticing the use for .closest, .next, .parent alot more now I am getting more into jQuery, so thanks a ton.